# HTTPError: Service Temporarily Unavailable (Multithreading download of Wikipedia data dumps)

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I am constantly getting this error when I try to download Wikipedia data dumps. Is it because I am making too many requests to download the files? I am using threading of 100.

On code 1:

```
def multithread_download_files_func(self,download_file):
    filename = download_file[download_file.rfind("/")+1:]
    save_file_w_submission_path = self.ptsf + filename
    if not os.path.exists(save_file_w_submission_path):
        opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
        opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
        urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(download_file)
        data_content = response.read()                 
    with open(save_file_w_submission_path, 'wb') as wf:    
        wf.write(data_content)
    return filename
```

Or even on code 2:

```
    request = urllib.request.Request(download_file)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    data_content = response.read()
```

Threading

```
p = ThreadPool(100)
results = p.map(self.multithread_download_files_func, matching_fnmatch_list)
for r in results:
    print(r)
```

Consistent Error:

```
  File "D:\Users\Jonathan\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTPError: Service Temporarily Unavailable
```

Url

```
https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-raw/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if someone else has a better solution, but I found a code and adjusted it to my need. It will loop on to the link until it gives me the result.

```
if not os.path.exists(save_file_w_submission_path):
    data_content = None
    try:
        request = urllib.request.Request(download_file)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
        data_content = response.read()     
    except urllib.error.HTTPError:
        retries = 1
        success = False
        while not success:
            try:
                response = urllib.request.urlopen(download_file)
                success = True
            except Exception:
                wait = retries * 30;
                print('Error! Waiting %s secs and re-trying...' % wait + '\n')
                sys.stdout.flush()
                time.sleep(wait)
                retries += 1
    if data_content:
        with open(save_file_w_submission_path, 'wb') as wf:    
            wf.write(data_content)
        print(filename)
```